# Magento 2 : Add variable in Page builder from url params

Tags: magento2, page-builder, custom-variable

I am looking to add variables in the Page Builder coming from the url parameters.

Do you have an idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Custom Variables from Admin Panel

Go to **Admin Dashboard**

Navigate to **System** -> **Other Settings** -> **Custom Variables**

On the TOp of Grid there is **Add New Variable** Button, Click on It

Save and Check in Page Builder Variable Section

Comment: Thx, but i don't understand who you call url params in custom variable